# Calculating both points of intersection on curve $x^2 + y^2 = 16$ and a point equidistant to both when given a straight line

Tags: vectors

Given the $y$-intercept and gradient of an infinite straight line on the Cartesian plane, how can I find both points of intersection (2D vector) if the line does pass through the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 16$ in terms of $m$ and $c$. In addition, I would like to find the point equidistant from both intersections.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I assume $m$ is gradient and $c$ is the $y$-intercept. What have you tried?

Comment: @Platehead Yes, that is correct. I'm only a GCSE student and so haven't tried a whole lot, but instead concluded that it could only be solved in a programmatic manner before coming here in hope of some enlightenment...

Comment: I've attached something that could get you started, let me know if it's still problematic.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is pretty easy. Got caught up in trig a little too much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Points of intersection occur when both equations are satisfied: meaning, all $(x,y)$ such that *both* equations
\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= 16\\
y &= mx + c
\end{align}
hold. You can substitute the second equation into the first, giving a quadratic in $x$. Depending on what $m$ and $c$ are, you can have 0 to 2 real solutions to this quadratic: either the line doesn't touch the circle at all (0 solutions), is tangent to it (1 solution) or passes through twice (2 solutions).

If there are two solutions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ the point equidistant is just averaging both coordinates:
$$
\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: I've come up with `x^2+(mx+c)^2=16`, is this the 'quadratic in x' you anticipated. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Get it into the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, and use the quadratic formula.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something here but how is this possible with three variables _m_, _x_ and _c_ where _a_ and _b_ are coefficients anyway? Surely expansion would cause all three of these variables to be risen to the second power. I have `x^2 + m^2x^2 + 2cmx + c^2 = 16` and have hit a brick wall. I cannot see any way of creating standard quadratic form.

Comment: You can factor that as $(1+m^2)x^2 + (2mc)x + (c^2-16) = 0$.

Comment: Done it! Thanks.